# How to add values to a dictionary of class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's my first time posting here. I'm currently facing a problem where my goal is for user to have a command where my dictionary of classes will add exp to the class argument. (I'm kinda bad at english if you want some clarification, Please let me know)

```
class Stats:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

stre = {1: Stats(name='Excercise', exp=0, description="This is a description"),
        2: Stats(name='Gym', exp=0, description="Gym description")}

def statsComm():
    command_list = ["stre", "inte", "will"]
    print("Select Command {}".format(command_list))
    command = input("> ")
    if command == 'stre':
        for key, value in stre.items():
            print(value.exp)


while True:
    print("Enter Command {}".format(command_list))
    command = input("> ")
    if command == 'stats':
        statsComm()
```

Currently it prints the right thing. But I don't know how to add value to exp of an individual class when they enter a command. Thank you :D

Comment: Have you tried `value.exp += 1`?

Comment: @berkelem I want individual classes to add value. If I did that it will add to everything right?

Comment: You can specify individual classes if you want. e.g. `if value.name == 'Exercise': value.exp += 1` etc.

Comment: @berkelem That solved my problem, thank you very much. I felt so dumb for not realizing that lol :DDD

Comment: Instead of changing the title of your question, you can instead post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. Feel free to accept it if it helped.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh ohhh. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify individual classes within the for loop as follows:

```
for key, value in stre.items():
    if value.name == 'Exercise': 
        value.exp += 1
```